# Replace bad spelling with correct spelling

Tags: computational-linguistics, transcription, dictionary, software

I have a large old text, written in language A but according to the spelling rules of language B. Words are understandable, but I need to make spelling correct according to the rules of A. How this can be done? What software may be used for this purpose?

Comment: Use regular expressions?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Regular expressions are usually not good enough for that.

Answer (score 1):

This task is called normalisation in Computational Linguistics and there are tools for it, e.g., VARD by Baron and Rayson. Those tools are typically trained on some manually crafted *gold standard* and than applied to the larger corpus.

Comment: Not just computational linguistics, this term is also used when describing the process of creating critical editions of historical texts as well. E.g. most editions of Icelandic sagas, or of the Eddas have had their spelling normalised (the fact this normalised spelling more closely resembles Modern Icelandic spelling is one of the reasons many people erroneously believe that Old Norse is basically identical to Modern Icelandic, the other big one being that they don't realise how archaic the Icelandic spelling is compared to the phonology)